# Setup CRON weekly backup

Tags: bash, backup, cron

I want to make a backup of my `/var/lib/mysql` and `/var/www` folders and save them as tar.gz files to my mounted network file server (uslons001).

Here is my bash file located in: `/bin/backups/mysqlbackup.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir /home/lv_admin/uslons001/`date +%d%m%y`
cd /home/lv_admin/uslons001/`date +%d%m%y`
tar -czf mysql.tar.gz /var/lib/mysql
tar -czf www.tar.gz /var/www
```

Which works PERFECTLY fine when I execute it in a cmd shell but when I setup the cron job it never runs, so I'm not setting the cron job up properly. My cron job looks like this.

```
   36 10 * * 5 /bin/backups/mysqlbackup.sh
```

..there is also nothing in the /var/log/cron.log file, so no errors are being logged. (even after enabling cron logging in the /etc/syslog.conf file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the location of the bash file to `/usr/local/mysqlbackup.sh`.  After doing so I did the following commands on the file:

```
cd /usr/local/
sudo chown [username] mysqlbackup.sh
sudo chmod -rwx mysqlbackup.sh
sudo chmod go= mysqlbackup.sh
```

then I stopped using `~$ crontab -e` as the command to edit the cron job and started using `sudo nano /etc/crontab` where I made a new job line with the following:

```
00 20    * * 5  root  /usr/local/mysqlbackup.sh
```

I started using this file instead because it enabled me to tell it which user should execute it.  After these changes the cron job works.

Answer (score 7):

Few points to make:

- Why are you using timestrings in `/etc/cron.weekly/` scripts at all? You're only supposed to put executable scripts in there. You don't need to crontab them or anything else. That will just duplicate their work. Look at `/etc/cron.daily/apt` for an example of what I'm talking about. It's just a plain script.
- Per geirha's comment, the file can't have an extension. Odd, I know, so rename it:

  ```
  sudo mv /etc/cron.weekly/mysqlbackup{.sh,}
  ```
- You need to run `sudo chmod +x /etc/cron.weekly/mysqlbackup` to make it executable. You can then test it by running it, using that path.
- If you leave it in `/etc/cron.weekly/`, the script is going to run as root. None of your `~/` links are going to work. Use full paths. I'd suggest that after you do the `mkdir` you `cd` into it and that will reduce the huge paths in subsequent commands. If you need the generated files to be owned by your user, make your script `chown` them to your user when it's done backing up.

  I don't see any reason for any of this to be root driven. You could plonk the script in your home directory and just use the standard `crontab -e` to add your rule and have it run. It still needs to be executable and I'd still recommend you use full paths, but it keeps the permissions slightly easier.

Comment: `sudo chmod +x /etc/cron.weekly/mysqlbackup.sh` would still not make the script run weekly. Cron ignores files with extensions in those directories. And in general, scripts shouldn't have extensions.

Comment: @geirha That is a *very* important comment! Is that documented anywhere?

Comment: @LimitedAtonement, If you look at the default `/etc/crontab`, `run-parts` is used to run the jobs in `/etc/cron.{daily,weekly,monthly}` if anacron is "not installed". [run-parts(8)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/run-parts.8.html) in turn explains what characters are allowed in the filenames. I believe the main reasoning behind it is to be able to easily disable a job by simply renaming `jobname` to `jobname.disabled` or similar.

Answer (score 2):

The day of the week is a numeric field, so it's failing  while trying to parse 'fri'.  Change that to 5 (sunday is 0). **edit:** I see the OP was updated to fix this and there are still issues, but they're addressed in other answers.

The cron format is well documented online, so I usually end up checking the docs before writing a new cron job: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Additionally, make sure you're using `crontab -e` (or similar) to edit your cron file, which will make sure it gets re-parsed.

Comment: fri and 5 are both valid. Not all implementations of cron allow you to use an abbreviation instead of a number for the weekday, but the cron in Ubuntu does. See `man 5 contab`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to redirect the errors from your cron line to a file, like:

`/usr/local/mysqlbackup.sh &>/var/log/mysqlcron.log`

That should catch both stdout and stderr and report if there is any syntax error, etc.

Note: if you are doing backup of a *live* database, you should use the specific utilities for the backup, like `mysqldump`, rather than using a generic tar command.
Reason is that if files inside /var/lib/mysql/ change while the tar is in execution you may end up with a inconsistent image of the database.

Comment: cron runs the job with sh unless you specifically tell it otherwise, and `&>` is not sh-syntax. `>file 2>&1` will work with both sh and bash.

Comment: True, good point.